# Is it possible to get the gps coordinates (latitude and longitude) that correspond with all of the census blocks in the United States?

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude, arcgis, census, tiger-census

I have a list of all of the census blocks (FIPS codes) in the US and I need to get the corresponding GPS codes for each of these.

I've tried looking on the census.gov site and their API, and I've found some other relevant resources like http://proximityone.com/ and ArcGIS (http://www.arcgis.com/index.html), but I can't seem to figure out how I would collect the gps coordinates of census blocks.

Does anyone here have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

There are shapefiles containing blocks/block groups for each state (https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php) which contains an attribute table with the following attributes:
STATEFP, COUNTYFP, TRACTCE, BLKGRPCE, GEOID, NAMELSAD, MTFCC, FUNCSTAT, ALAND, AWATER, INTPTLAT, INTPTLON

The last two columns of the dbf contain the centroid of each block.

There is also a gdb a few pages up from the link provided above (~2GB) which would contain the same information for all states.